# Ordering of objects in list_field in Django 2.2.1

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I just upgraded a project from Django 1.11.20 to Django 2.2.1 and noticed that the order in my list_filter:s was a bit random.

Has the ordering my the Model's ordering-property been removed in later (than 1.11.20) Django versions?

This is my Model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    organization_number = CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    disable_auto_creation_of_invoices = BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I took a look at the queries and this is the query for getting Customers in the RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter filter in Django 2.2.1:

```
SELECT
`core_customer`.`id`, `core_customer`.`name`, 
`core_customer`.`organization_number`, 
`core_customer`.`disable_auto_creation_of_invoices`
FROM `core_customer` WHERE `core_customer`.`id` IN (SELECT
DISTINCT U0.`customer_id`
FROM `time_report_timereportentry` U0)
```

And this is the query in Django 1.11.20:

```
SELECT
`core_customer`.`id`, `core_customer`.`name`, 
`core_customer`.`organization_number`, 
`core_customer`.`disable_auto_creation_of_invoices`
FROM `core_customer` WHERE `core_customer`.`id` IN (SELECT
DISTINCT U0.`customer_id` AS Col1
FROM `time_report_timereportentry` U0) ORDER BY `core_customer`.`name` ASC
```

As you can see there's an ORDER BY in Django 1.11.20, but it's missing in Django 2.2.1.

Do you have any ideas on how to get the objects sorted by the ordering-property?

And it seems like a normal list_filter (without RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter) also doesn't order by the ordering property.

Thanks for any help to sort(!) this out.

Comment: If I recall correctly it has not been removed, but if I understand correctly it is no longer taken into account when using a `JOIN`.

Comment: That sucks ... I've tested this in various Django versions and the ordering works up until 2.1.8, but in 2.2a the ordering doesn't work anymore.

Comment: yes, it apparently is written in the release notes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#model-meta-ordering-will-no-longer-affect-group-by-queries

Comment: But this isn't a GROUP BY query? And it's only deprecated, right?

Comment: Having the same problem, there's a ticket open on this: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30449

Answer (score 1):

You can order the data from your Models, let's say you have a model called Shop and you want to order by name, just add a class Meta inside of your model.

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['name']
```

Comment: My Model has `class Meta: ordering = ["name"]` (I'll update the question with info regarding that) ... using the same model in Django 1.11.20 gets the list sorted, but it doesn't get sorted in Django 2.2.1.

Comment: I've updated the question with my model, and it is the correct model. Also, the ordering works (running the same code) if I change to Django versions below 2.2a.